# Facebook Social Login With Vuejs

Tags: laravel, facebook, vue.js

I am using Laravel Vuejs, i am trying to do social login using vue-social-auth plugin, when i click to login with fb button, the new facebook window opens. But The client id and redirect is not passing in the URL thats why it gives me error. Kindly Tell me where was the issue
I am sharing the screenshot also, please chcek. 
[image]

Comment: Looks like app id is incorrect

Comment: Please go read [ask]. It isn’t possible for us to tell what might be wrong, based on just a screenshot like this. Since the parameter `client_id` is in the URL, only the value is left empty, first guess would be that you left some config settings empty. And the `redirect_uri` should be absolute, I don’t think a relative one will work.

Comment: 'facebook' => [
        'client_id'     => env('FACEBOOK_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_SECRET'),
        'redirect'      => env('FACEBOOK_URL'),
    ],
This is my services.php, and i defined it in .env file also

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer since I am not able to see what you have done in the code.

From the URL I can see that your client Id is empty so please make sure

1. You have your client_id, Client_secret and Redirect_url in the .env file
2. Try `php artisan config:cache`
3. Try `php artisan cache:clear`

That should solve your problem. Also please give more details about the  problem, not just a screenshot.

Comment: yes i did these things, these are right, but the thing is, why id is not passed with the url

Comment: Are you trying it in local? if its local are you trying using virtualhost ? or using Artisan serve?

Also try to echo env('client_id') and let me know the output

Comment: i am using it in localhost, using artisan serve, ok let me echo client id, will let you know

Comment: In that case please shut down the artisan server, run config:cache and cache:clear and then run php artisan serve again.

Comment: Can you echo the client id from .env?

Comment: Umm can you send me your .env file? and the controller code as well?

Comment: Also instead of config:cache try running config:clear.
Then restart the artisan server.

Comment: do not send stuff around, ALWAYS include all relevant details and code in your question. just saying. think about people who visit this later and may have the same problem.